# how to get system DateTime in webservice

Tags: asp.net, sql

i am trying to get the system date and time in my webservice. but i not sure on how to do it.

this is my code :

```
 public void InsertStudentTransaction(string Name, string CLass, string NRIC, string StallNo, string AmountSpent, DateTime Date)
     {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nConnectionString2"].ConnectionString))
     {
        int StallNo1 = int.Parse(StallNo);
        float AmountSpent1 = float.Parse(AmountSpent);
        Date = DateTime.Now;

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT Into StudentTransactions (Name, CLass,NRIC,StallNo,AmountSpent, TimeDate) VALUES (@Name, @CLass, @NRIC, @StallNo, @AmountSpent, @Date)", conn);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CLass", CLass);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NRIC", NRIC);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StallNo",StallNo1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AmountSpent", AmountSpent1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeDate", Date);

        conn.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
  }
```

Comment: You already have it `DateTime.Now` what exactly is the question?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: yeah i have tried i am trying to read system date Time from my web service and insert into my database.

Comment: i have tried the bottom code but it gave me this error : System.ArgumentException: Cannot convert  to System.DateTime.
Parameter name: type ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: System.ArgumentException: Cannot convert to System.DateTime. Parameter name: type ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: How is @TimeDate declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error response, I assume that the problem is not in your code, but in the addressing of this method. You're probably trying to parse a string value into a `DateTime` format, somewhat like this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dateAsString);
```

If the dateAsString variable does not contain a valid date, then the ArgumentException you described will be thrown.

You can resolve this by trying to find out what's wrong with the string date you're trying to parse. It could very well be an empty string that's causing the problem. To help you with finding the troublemaker, use [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) to throw a new Exception with some helpful information:

```
DateTime date;

if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateAsString, out date)
{
   throw new Exception("Invalid date: " + dateAsString);
}
```

Comment: hey, i have tried to run it but i got this error :"System.ArgumentException: Cannot convert  to System.DateTime.
Parameter name: type ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
"